# Expand column containing key value pairs into their own columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['''[{"key":"Gender","value":["Men"]},
  {"key":"Shoe Size","value":["M"]},
  {"key":"Shoe Category","value":["Men's Shoes"]},
  {"key":"Color","value":["Multicolor"]},
  {"key":"Manufacturer Part Number","value":["8190-W-NAVY-7.5"]},
  {"key":"Brand","value":["Josmo"]}]''',

  '''[{"key":"Gender","value":["Women"]},
  {"key":"Size","value":["XL"]},
 {"key":"Heel Height","value":["1 Inches"]}]'''], 

  'y':['A','B']})
```

It is basically a list of key-value pairs that I wish to extract to their own columns and the keys are not consistent between rows.

Any ideas on how to go about it?

Comment: Also, the length of the list is not consistent between rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. However, you have to find out all the possible key values beforehand. I guess, it could be done programmatically, but I have hard-coded them here. Also, if there are multiple items in value, it will take the first one.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['''[{"key":"Gender","value":["Men"]},
  {"key":"Shoe Size","value":["M"]},
  {"key":"Shoe Category","value":["Men's Shoes"]},
  {"key":"Color","value":["Multicolor"]},
  {"key":"Manufacturer Part Number","value":["8190-W-NAVY-7.5"]},
  {"key":"Brand","value":["Josmo"]}]''',

  '''[{"key":"Gender","value":["Women"]},
  {"key":"Shoe Size","value":["M"]},
  {"key":"Shoe Category","value":["Women's Shoes"]},
  {"key":"Color","value":["Multicolor"]},
  {"key":"Manufacturer Part Number","value":["8190-W-NAVY-7.5"]}]'''], 

  'y':['A','B']})

expanded_columns = ['Gender', 'Shoe Size', 'Shoe Category', 'Color',
                    'Manufacturer Part Number', 'Brand']

# function to create list of values from json text
def json_to_cols(s):
  l = json.loads(s)
  d = {i:None for i in expanded_columns}

  for row in l:
    d[row['key']] = row['value'][0]

  return list(d.values())

# Create new dataframe with expanded columns
df1 = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(json_to_cols(row['x']), index=expanded_columns),
            axis=1)    
new_df = df.join(df1)
print(new_df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this definitely helps.

How do I go about doing it if the keys are not consistent between rows like in the edited OP?

Thanks!

Comment: Found a way to do it by first collecting all possible 'expanded_columns' and then using your code. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but the following code will generate a dataframe in which the column names are taken from `y`, the index is taken from the keys from `x`, and the values for each column are taken from the values in `x`, with `NaN` for any key that didn't appear.

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame(
            {input_row[1]['y']:
                {
                        pair['key']: pair['value'][0] 
                        for pair in ast.literal_eval(input_row[1]['x'])
                }
                for input_row in df.iterrows()
            }      
        )
```

output:

```
                                   A         B
Brand                               Josmo       NaN
Color                          Multicolor       NaN
Gender                                Men     Women
Heel Height                           NaN  1 Inches
Manufacturer Part Number  8190-W-NAVY-7.5       NaN
Shoe Category                 Men's Shoes       NaN
Shoe Size                               M       NaN
Size                                  NaN        XL
```